# How to create a to do list with only javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, list, dom, events

How can I create a to do list with just javascript? I have a html file with only 1 div and have to do this with just javascript?
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLpJI.png)

This is my html file...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>To do App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The rule is that I can't add more html tags
Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Well, you have to add more tags.**

You don't have to write those tags into your HTML file, you can create elements using JS.

Components that you can create in JS

1. Search Bar
2. Todo Item
3. Button

After writing these components you can plug and play your logic.